# What does it mean for a solution to a Linear DE to be homogeneous?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I'm a physics student and I've just being going over some definitions for differential equations. I don't think I fully understand what a homogeneous equation is and the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_homogeneous_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equations_with_constant_coefficients) says that a Linear DE has **homogeneous solutions** which add to form other homogeneous solutions. **What does it mean for a solution to be homogeneous?**

Usually, a DE is said to be homogeneous if it is equal to zero. eg:

$$u'' + u' -4u = 0$$

But that's not the full story is it? This definition of "homogeneous" is making me think that a homogeneous solution is equal to zero. Alas, mathematicians, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of a homogeneous equation is your 
$$u'' -u'+4u=0.\tag{H}$$
It is a very special homogeneous equation, since it has constant coefficients.

Consider the **inhomogeneous** equation 
$$u''-u'+4u=e^t.\tag{I}$$
The article discusses, among other things, the fact that we can find all solutions of the inhomogeneous equation (I)  by a) finding the **general** solution of the homogeneous equation (H), b) finding a single **particular** solution of the inhomogeneous equation (I), and c) adding the solutions found in a) and b).

Then the article focuses on finding the general solution of equations like (H), and shows that a linear combination of solutions of a homogeneous equation is always a solution of the equation.

These are solutions of the homogeneous equation, and not "homogeneous solutions."
In the context of linear differential equations, homogeneous solution has no meaning.

Comment: Yes, I checked with my professor and he said that it doesn't mean anything. I guess I ought to update the Wiki article. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome.